# C# How to make paddles move smoothly

Tags: c#, pong

Making pong for my school C# project and need help getting the paddles to move smoothly. Currently when they move they feel very heavy. I'm only a beginner with C# so this is what I've got so far.

```
   void MovePaddle1(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.W:
                {
                    paddle1.Top -= 20;
                    break;
                }

            case Keys.S:
                {
                    paddle1.Top += 20;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    void MovePaddle2(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.I:
                {
                    paddle2.Top -= 20;
                    break;
                }

            case Keys.K:
                {
                    paddle2.Top += 20;
                    break;
                }

        }
    }

    private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (gameIsRunning == true)
        {
            //Move the paddles
            MovePaddle1(e.KeyCode);
            MovePaddle2(e.KeyCode);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Change 20 to a smaller value. It will move in smaller increments.

Also, never hard code values. Use a constant instead.

```
const int SPEED = 5;
...
paddle1.Top -= SPEED;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this algorithm?
First declare the animaton speed and the targeted position variables:

```
float Speed = 0.1;
float TargetPos1 = 0;
float TargetPos2 = 0;
```

Update in each frame the animation (the actual Paddle position)

```
Paddle1.Top += (TargetPos1 - Paddle1.Top) * Speed;
Paddle2.Top += (TargetPos2 - Paddle2.Top) * Speed;
```

If you want to change the position of the paddles now you need to change the TargetPos variables:

```
TargetPos1 -= 20; //move paddle1 20 pixels down
TargetPos2 += 20; //move paddle2 20 pixels up
```

What it actually does is that the paddle is moving constantly towards the 
`TargetPos`-position but the further the paddle is away from this point the faster it moves. This creates a smooth animation. Also quite useful for camera zooming and follow camera movement e.g. in platformer games. For a pong game I would prefer a higher `Speed` value for a faster movement when a fast reaction is required.

Oh, and in your if-statement in the last function you can just write:

```
if (gameIsRunning)
{
    //Move the paddles...
}
```

As a beginner think a bit about it, I promise it safe you some time in the future :)